# dancer2 pages not displayed throught lighttpd

Tags: perl, lighttpd, dancer

I just installed dancer, and tried a short example

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Dancer2;

get '/' => sub {
return 'Hello World!';
};

start;
```

but i dont seem to get any output at `localhost/cgi-bin/test.pl`.

I think my lighttpd server is configured fairly correctly because if i replace the above text with this the page is displayed.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

start;
$date = `date`;
$reddit = `curl -L www.google.com`;
print<<END;
<html>
    <head>
        <h2>Hello</h2>
    </head>
    <title>
        $date
    </title>
    <body>
        $reddit
    </body>
</html>
END
```

However, if i use `localhost:3000` then the dancer's scripts displays correctly

this is my lighttpd.conf file, and i don't think i have changed much

```
server.modules = (
        "mod_access",
        "mod_alias",
        "mod_compress",
        "mod_redirect",
#       "mod_rewrite",
)

server.document-root        = "/var/www/test"
server.upload-dirs          = ( "/var/cache/lighttpd/uploads" )
server.errorlog             = "/var/log/lighttpd/error.log"
server.pid-file             = "/var/run/lighttpd.pid"
server.username             = "www-data"
server.groupname            = "www-data"
server.port                 = 80
server.chroot               = "/"

index-file.names            = ( "index.pl", "index.php", "index.html", "index.lighttpd.html" )
url.access-deny             = ( "~", ".inc" )
static-file.exclude-extensions = ( ".php", ".pl", ".fcgi" )
compress.cache-dir          = "/var/cache/lighttpd/compress/"
compress.filetype           = ( "application/javascript", "text/css", "text/html", "text/plain" )

# default listening port for IPv6 falls back to the IPv4 port
include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/use-ipv6.pl " + server.port
include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/create-mime.assign.pl"
include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/include-conf-enabled.pl"
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [manual](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer::Deployment#Using-Lighttpd):

> Using Lighttpd
>
> You can use Lighttp's mod_proxy:
>
> ```
> $HTTP["url"] =~ "/application" {
>     proxy.server = (
>         "/" => (
>             "application" => ( "host" => "127.0.0.1", "port" => 3000 )
>         )
>     )
> }
> ```

This configuration will proxy all request to the /application path to the path / on localhost:3000.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? what is "application", can it be something like "*"?